# Error while splitting dataframe in R (Using sample.split)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 140 rows and I'm splitting data randomly to test data and training data.

But while splitting the data using sample.split method in caTools library, I encountered an error.

Following is my code:

```
library(caTools)

set.seed(42)

features <- read.csv(file = './featur.csv', header = TRUE)
features

features$split = sample.split(features,SplitRatio = 0.8)
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, split, value = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE,  : 
  replacement has 18 rows, data has 140
```

Can anyone give a clue on what's causing this error and how I can fix it?

Comment: I plan to then use this 'split' column to set training and test data.

Comment: The output of `sample.split` shouldn't be a column in the data.frame. Try instead `i_split<- sample.split(row.names(features), 0.8); train<-features[i_split, ]; test<-features[!i_split, ]`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently user @RuiBarrads from the comment told me that the output of sample.split shouldn't be a column. I changed that, and it fixed it.